# DynamoDB: ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key email in the item

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb, joi

I am new to Dynamodb. I have created one DynamoDB table. By using [dynamodb-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb) and for validation I am using `joi`. I am confused and facing couple of issues. First, when I checked my AWS' Dynamodb dashboard, I don't see content and tags items even though it's in my Schema, [image: My AWS' dynamodb dashboard]. Then I am trying to post data to my Blogpost database by using  Postman, ([image: This is how do I post it]). But I am getting error like this: `ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key email in the item`.

**This is my dynamoDb setup**

```
var dynamo = require("dynamodb");
const Joi = require("joi");
dynamo.AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "AKIAIBJS4SX3SWW**",
  secretAccessKey: "8O1dsZrIM43q8OF4kO/lMToW**",
  region: "us-east-1"
});

var BlogPost = dynamo.define("BlogPost", {
  hashKey: "email",
  rangeKey: "title",
  schema: {
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    title: Joi.string(),
    content: Joi.binary(),
    tags: dynamo.types.stringSet()
  }
});

dynamo.createTables(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error creating tables: ", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Tables has been created");
  }
});

module.exports = BlogPost;
```

**This is my express server**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const BlogPost = require("./db");

app.post("/post", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logs = new BlogPost(req.body);
    const entry = await logs.save();
    res.json(entry);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(422);
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(` App is listening at port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `req.body` does not include `email` property or the property is an empty string.

Apply `body-parser` for your express server, something like:

```
...
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
...
```